# Using @input and @output between Angular 2 child components

Tags: html, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have an `ng-table` which is a child component of my main page. When a row is clicked, it sends the information in that row via `onCellClick` using an `EventEmitter`. I'm trying to send this information to another child component. This happens to be a button which is the child of a Bootstrap 4 modal which pops up when a button on the main page is clicked. Just having trouble with the receiving and manipulation of that information.[image: This is the main page. The Bootstrap modal pops up whe the center button of the set of three is clicked.][image: Bootstrap modal]

HTML of child component table:

```
<ng-table [config]="config"
      (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)"
      (cellClicked)="onCellClick($event)"
      [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
</ng-table>
```

HTML for the child component (this appears in the main page's HTML):

```
<app-datatable (row)="received($event)"></app-datatable>
```

Typescript for getting and sending the row's data (`this.row` is the EvenEmitter. `data.row` is the actual row that's clicked on):

```
@Output() row: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
public onCellClick(data: any): any {
  let d = data.row.tDataPoint;
  let i = data.row.tICCP;
  let s = data.row.tStartDate;
  let e = data.row.tEndDate;
  let toSend:DataTable = new DataTable(d, i, s, e);
  this.row.emit(toSend);
}
```

HTML for the button that is the child component of the Bootstrap 4 modal:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onClick($event)">Delete</button>
```

Typescript for the button child component:

```
selector: 'deletebutton'
@Input() receivedRow:DataTable;
onClick(message:DataTable){
  this.sender.emit('This is from On Click Deletebutton');
  console.log("On Click Deletebutton");
  console.log(this.receivedRow);
  for (let entry in DPS){
    if (DPS[entry].tDataPoint===message.tDataPoint){
    DPS.splice(parseInt(entry),1);
    }
  }
}
```

HTML of the button child component (this appears in the modal's HTML). This is what should actually be receiving the data from the clicked row as input.

```
<deletebutton [receivedRow]='row'></deletebutton>
```

Right now in my `onClick` method is saying `receivedRow` is undefined. I feel like what is missing is the coordination between `[receivedRow]='row'` where I have my `deletebutton` HTML and the `onClick` function call in the HTML for that child component. Overall, I just want to click a row, click the button to open the delete Boostrap Modal, and have the correct row be deleted I click the `Delete` button inside the modal. Let me know if something's not clear or more code is needed.

Is there actually a way to communicate between child components like this using @Input and @Output?

Comment: Your architecture is unclear to me. Maybe post a diagram or give more details.

Comment: Added screenshots of main page and Bootstrap modal to question. The `ng-table` HTML is what is in the HTML for the child component. Then I use the `app-datatable` tag to place that component on the main page since `app-datatable` is that component's selector. The first set of Typescript is how I send the row's information via EventEmitter. The `button` HTML is the HTML for the `Delete` button inside the Bootstrap Modal. This is what I'm trying to send the row's data to. The Typescript after that is attempting to manipulate the row's data based on the `@Input`.

Comment: Then the final `deletebutton` HTML is the HTML that I use to actually render the `Delete` button in the Bootstrap modal. Let me if this clears things up or you need more information

Comment: So the delete button is not by row right ? It's for the whole table ?

Comment: There is only one `deletebutton` and if I understand your question correctly, it is for the whole table. It is designed to receive the data of whichever row you click on.

Comment: What's the point of having only one button if you want to receive data of clicked row ? Why don't you just put a button per row ?

Comment: Would it help you to have an example with a table and a remove button on each row that delete the row ?

Comment: That's actually what I originally had, but the requirements for the project want it this way. Says it's less clutter on the page, etc.

Comment: Having an example like that could help. Not totally sure, but  it could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat of a work around is to place the Delete button component in the HTML for the table component like this:

```
<ng-table [config]="config"
      (tableChanged)="onChangeTable(config)"
      (cellClicked)="onCellClick($event)"
      [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
</ng-table>
<deletebutton [receivedRow]='toSend'></deletebutton>
```

And still leave the table's tag in the main page's HTML like I had it:

```
<app-datatable (row)="received($event)"></app-datatable>
```

And now the row's data is being sent to that Delete button since it is technically a part of the child component of the main page.

Still not able to communicate between child components like I asked in my question though. But this is something close that works.

Answer (score 1):

With angular2, your data flow should be :
- **down to pass data**
- **up to send events**

So if you really want to go this way, you should have something like that :

[image: diagram]

**I think there's a better way tho :**
For your app AND for your user, it'd be best to have a remove button on each line. This way, it avoid the user to be confused clicking on a row and then click on a remove button and within your code you'll be able to do something like that :

**src/app.html** :

```
<table class="table">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of tableData">
    <td *ngFor="let column of row.columns">
      {{ column.name }}
    </td>

    <td (click)="deleteRow(row)"><button>X</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button (click)="addRow()">Add a row</button>
```

**src/app.ts** *(troncated here to the class only)* :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: `./src/app.html`,
})
export class App {
  private tableData;
  private cptRow = 1;

  constructor() {
    this.tableData = [
      {
        idRow: `idR${this.cptRow++}`,
        columns: [
          {idColumn: 'idR1C1', name: 'Column 1-1'},
          {idColumn: 'idR1C2', name: 'Column 1-2'},
          {idColumn: 'idR1C3', name: 'Column 1-3'}
        ]
      },
      {
        idRow: `idR${this.cptRow++}`,
        columns: [
          {idColumn: 'idR2C1', name: 'Column 2-1'},
          {idColumn: 'idR2C2', name: 'Column 2-2'},
          {idColumn: 'idR2C3', name: 'Column 2-3'}
        ]
      },
      {
        idRow: `idR${this.cptRow++}`,
        columns: [
          {idColumn: 'idR3C1', name: 'Column 3-1'},
          {idColumn: 'idR3C2', name: 'Column 3-2'},
          {idColumn: 'idR3C3', name: 'Column 3-3'}
        ]
      }
    ];
  }

  deleteRow(row) {
    // we can do this by reference ...
    // this.tableData = this.tableData.filter(r => r !== row);

    // or by ID
    this.tableData = this.tableData.filter(r => r.idRow !== row.idRow);
  }

  addRow() {
    this.tableData.push({
      idRow: `idR${this.cptRow}`,
      columns: [
        {idColumn: `idR${this.cptRow}C1`, name: `Column ${this.cptRow}-1`},
        {idColumn: `idR${this.cptRow}C2`, name: `Column ${this.cptRow}-2`},
        {idColumn: `idR${this.cptRow}C3`, name: `Column ${this.cptRow}-3`}
      ]
    });

    this.cptRow++;
  }
}
```

Here's a working Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/hNhcdraoDNnI2C92TQvr?p=preview

Now, if you really want to use input/output properties, you should look for tutorials because the structure here seems a bit confused. I can help you to understand that (and it's important to understand it with angular2 !) but maybe you should give me a shout on [Gitter/Angular](https://gitter.im/angular/angular) instead of detailing Angular2 flow here :)